# CSS transitions, animations have terrible performance, behavior

Tags: google-chrome, css, webkit

[I'm working on a page turn animation](http://chearon.github.com/PageTurn/).  The performance is disappointing.  Particularly if you take the `pages` class and make it something like 800px wide (paste `$('.pages').css({width: '960px', height: '600px'});` into your console).  I used to have around 16 transitions running at once and reduced it to 9, many of which are transforms!  I don't know what else I can do.

Chrome does not seem to be using the GPU.  It spikes the FPS on initial page turn but then dips down at regular intervals (enabled this with `about:flags`):

[image: Chrome showing FPS dips]

Try it out in Safari and you will get better performance but see that the animations do not sync up, often lag behind each other, and there's a weird wobblyness that [Román Cortés's project also suffered from](http://www.romancortes.com/ficheros/page-flip.html) in the same browser (I haven't made it work in Fx yet).

There hasn't been much good material about how to optimize CSS transitions and animations on the web and I've been mostly teaching myself.  I was hoping someone would have this kind of advice.

Answer (score 4):

In order to take advantage of the GPU you have to use `translate3d(x,y,z)` instead of `translate(x,y)` in your -webkit-tranform's. This will force Chrome to use the GPU to render the animations.

Beware that while the performance will greatly increase if the computer has a good video card, it will also degrade on a slower hardware.

Comment: Thanks, I tried translate3d on Chrome/MacOS and it was horrendously slow when I had 12 pages of somewhat complicated DOM structures.  The whole page slowed to a crawl before I even animated anything!  So unfortunately I can't figure out a way to get it to not cripple one platform while accelerating another.

Answer (score 3):

Here's [a page flip I did](http://dev.sencha.com/animator/demos/pageflip/) for our launch of Sencha Animator. It's also inspired by Ramon Cortes' original, but uses different mechanisms - as far I as remember. It's super smooth in Safari and on iOS, but kind of jerky on Chrome desktop. Haven't checked it in Android 4 yet though.

Comment: Nice, I will have to study this technique as Safari seems to like it better.  However, Chrome on Mac renders it with random chunks of pixels turning to black or revealing the layer beneath at random.

Comment: Yes, apparently Chrome 15(?)'s webkit version has a bug where implicit z-orders get messed up when transforms are added. I'm going to tackle a version with explicit z-index settings and see if it fixes things.

Comment: I just figured out if you add `-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d` it doesn't flicker like that.  I still get some clipping where it shouldn't though.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Chrome 17 on OSX, and it seems fine - runs at around 20-30fps, no dipping or graphical issues. I suspect that this is just an issue with older Chrome builds.

Answer (score 2):

Animating box-shadows and -webkit-gradients is very expensive, try removing them temporarily to see if it improves performance. If it does, see what you can do to replace them with images.